# hs_err_pidxxx.log files keep appearing in root folder macOS Mojave

Tags: mac, java

I have been researching hs_err_pidxxx.log files online for weeks and the only information I can find is that they are error logs generated by Java in plain text.

First, these files have been popping up in my root directory (Macintosh HD) sporadically ever since I got this computer.  They usually appear while the computer is sleeping, around 2 o'clock in the morning.

Second, I uninstalled the Java runtime from this Mac several months ago and have used "deep uninstall" apps to make sure all Java-related files have been deleted from the computer.

Finally, the files that appear on my computer are not readable.  Whether their content is binary or plain text I cannot tell but the contents are pure gibberish and do not contain any readable words.

Could someone help me figure out what these files are and where they are coming from (they do not seem to fit the description, as stated above, of what everyone else's posts on the internet say they are).

Addendum (2019.02.13):

Below are the results of the launchctl command suggested by @MMB yesterday:

> Label
>   com.bitdefender.AuthHelperTool
>   com.bitdefender.CoreIssues
>   com.bitdefender.Daemon
>   com.bitdefender.UpdDaemon
>   com.bitdefender.agent
>   com.bitdefender.credentials
>   com.bitdefender.upgrade
>   com.teamviewer.Helper
>   com.vix.cron
>   net.tunnelblick.tunnelblick.tunnelblickd
>   org.cups.cupsd
>   org.serviio.server

Note that BitDefender AntiVirus was not installed at the time this problem started occurring.  The latest log file generated, though, is hs_err_pid208.log and PID 208 is com.apple.usbd, not any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

These occur when a JVM crashes and these are the equivalent of core files for debugging. You can't read them because they're likely from a service launched by root.

Regardless, it appears you still have Java on your system, which isn't too surprising given some vendors with Java-based apps shipped their own JVM so they didn't have version issues or require the user to manually install Java in addition to their own app. If memory serves, Crashplan, a backup app used to do this, but Java has fallen out of favor, so it's probably an older app or service (which also probably explains why it is crashing).

There's an easy resolution via the Terminal, though. Take the PID number (xxx) from the log filename and search the process table for it. For example, if the PID were 13924, then

```
~ ps -e | grep 13924
13924 ??         0:07.79 /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino
```

I don't believe I have any of said apps on my system anymore, so I just used the Arduino app as an example, but with that information, you should be able to determine where the Java runtime is located. From there you can figure out the proper way to uninstall the guilty app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @MMB The only results for the code above, at the time, pointed to the built-in file for the ColorSync daemon, which confused me. A new log file appeared today and the results for the ps command this time returned: `208 ?? 0:00.06 /usr/libexec/usbd`. Again, a built-in macOS file, not an application. How could macOS' own usb daemon cause a Java error?

Comment: Puzzling. According the man pages, `usbd` arrived in 10.9 as a way for iOS devices to charge and send notifications.

Comment: Let's tackle this a different way. Given Apple's disdain for Java, let us assume the file isn't coming from Apple software. You also said the files are created around 2AM, which suggests something launched. Try the following command, which the results of which you might want to append to your original question: `sudo launchctl list | cut -f3 | grep -v com.apple | sort`

Comment: The above command will generate a list of services launched by third-party software that you have installed. Note that since the `sudo` command is issued, you'll need to enter your password.

Comment: Four Java crash logs later @MMB and one finally appeared today with a useful PID - revealing that there is indeed a JRE installed on my Mac, contained in the Serviio Media Server.  I plan to uninstall Serviio, which should stop the Java error logs from appearing, but I am beginning to fear that these Java logs are just a symptom of my main problem and not the cause of what is making my computer crash at 2:10 AM every one to three days, during sleep mode.  I have looked at many diverse crash logs now, in the Console, and every one that has a time stamp of 2:10 AM is in unreadable text or code.

Comment: It may not be, but start by removing Serviio and then tackle the next issue.